# Using getResource with ProGuard results in null result

Tags: java, proguard

Using ProGuard on my jar files has broken my calls to `class.getResource("")`. I have seen that in the ProGuard manual you need to specify the `-keepdirectories mypackage` ([manual link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html#keepdirectories)). However, I have specified the `-keepdirectories` option and it doesn't seem to be working. I think there is something wrong with my ProGuard configuration. I have also looked at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848761/how-can-i-force-proguard-to-keep-my-xml-resource-file), but I am having trouble getting the `-keeppackagenames` working as well.

In my code I have something similar to the following.

```
package com.example.mypackage;
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        //url is always returned as null
        URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("");
        //do additional stuff including retrieving manifest file
    }
}
```

ProGuard Configuration

```
-injars ...
-outjars ...
-libraryjars ...

-dontoptimize
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumber,Table,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-repackageclasses
-overloadaggressively

-keep public class com.example.mypackage.MyClass{
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
-keepdirectories com.example.mypackage,com.example.mypackage.MyClass
-keeppackagenames com.example.mypackage,com.example.mypackage.MyClass
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ProGuard expects dots in packages names, and slashes in file names and directory names:

```
-keeppackagenames com.example.mypackage
-keepdirectories  com/example/mypackage
```

Comment: Adding the `/` to `keepdirectories` did the trick! I've marked this as the correct answer.

Comment: Beware! The specified path may not end with a slash: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/521/

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to get it working with the following modification to `-keepdirectories`

```
-keepdirectories **mypackage**
```

However, this feels sort of clunky, and while it works, I feel as if there is a better solution out there.