# License file not present in my final APK if i am using proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard, dexguard

I added my license file into MYExampleApp->src folder.

If i generate the APK without using proguard my license file is present in Meta-Inf folder. but if i am using proguard the license file is not present in Meta-Inf folder.

I want include my license file int Meta-Inf folder.

How can i achieve this?
Please help me!

Comment: I think you have to change proguard configurations to exclude your license file. Here is some reference for proguard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard

Comment: yes you are correct ,in the link which you have provided it was given for only java class files,i want to do it the same for text files my license file under src folder

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need to mention in proguard file to keep the file. Please refer the link below -

[How can I force Proguard to keep my .xml resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848761/how-can-i-force-proguard-to-keep-my-xml-resource-file)